# Not able to pull data from an API and plot the data in React

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

I've an API

> [http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid={API_KEY}](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

I'm trying to fetch data from that API and plot data by using [react-google-charts](https://react-google-charts.com/).
Code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'


// charts
import Chart from "react-google-charts";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    }
  }));
  

  export default function Dashboard() {
    initialState = { 
        dataLoadingStatus: 'loading', 
        chartData: [] 
    }; 
    didMount = { async function(params) {
            const response = await fetch (
                'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=bengaluru&appid={API_KEY}',
            )
            const json = await response.json()
            const temp_min = Object.keys(json.main.temp_min)
            const temp_max = Object.values(json.main.temp_max)
            const chartData = [['temp_min', 'temp_max']]
            for (let i = 0; i < temp_min.length; i += 1) {
                chartData.push([temp_min[i], temp_max[i]])
            }
            component.setState({
                dataLoadingStatus: 'ready',
                chartData: chartData,
            })
        }
    }
    const classes = useStyles();
    return component.state.dataLoadingStatus === 'ready' ? (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div container>
                <h2>
                    Weather Data
                </h2>
            </div>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
                    <Card className={classes.root}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                Sample Data
                            </Typography>
                            <Chart
                            chartType="ColumnChart"
                            loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                            data={
                                data = component.state.chartData
                            }
                            options={{
                            title: 'Temparature data',
                            chartArea: { width: '100%' },
                            hAxis: {
                                title: 'Temparature',
                                minValue: 0,
                            },
                            vAxis: {
                                title: 'Temparature',
                            },
                            }}
                            legendToggle
                        />
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={6}>
                    <Card className={classes.root}>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                Sample Data
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <Chart
                            width={400}
                            height={300}
                            chartType="BubbleChart"
                            loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                            data={[
                                ['ID', 'Life Expectancy', 'Fertility Rate', 'Region', 'Population'],
                                ['CAN', 80.66, 1.67, 'North America', 33739900],
                                ['DEU', 79.84, 1.36, 'Europe', 81902307],
                                ['DNK', 78.6, 1.84, 'Europe', 5523095],
                                ['EGY', 72.73, 2.78, 'Middle East', 79716203],
                                ['GBR', 80.05, 2, 'Europe', 61801570],
                                ['IRN', 72.49, 1.7, 'Middle East', 73137148],
                                ['IRQ', 68.09, 4.77, 'Middle East', 31090763],
                                ['ISR', 81.55, 2.96, 'Middle East', 7485600],
                                ['RUS', 68.6, 1.54, 'Europe', 141850000],
                                ['USA', 78.09, 2.05, 'North America', 307007000],
                            ]}
                            options={{
                            title:
                                'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate ' +
                                'and population of some world countries (2010)',
                            hAxis: { title: 'Life Expectancy' },
                            vAxis: { title: 'Fertility Rate' },
                            bubble: { textStyle: { fontSize: 11 }},
                            }}
                        />
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div>Fetching data from API</div>
    )
}
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

> Line 21:5:  'initialState' is not defined  no-undef
> Line 25:5:  'didMount' is not defined      no-undef
> Line 36:13: 'component' is not defined     no-undef
> Line 43:12: 'component' is not defined    no-undef
> Line 61:37: 'data' is not defined          no-undef
> Line 61:44: 'component' is not defined     no-undef
> What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not using var, let, or const when you're declaring the variables.

```
Line 21:5: 'initialState' is not defined no-undef
Line 25:5: 'didMount' is not defined no-undef
Line 36:13: 'component' is not defined no-undef
Line 43:12: 'component' is not defined no-undef
Line 61:37: 'data' is not defined no-undef
Line 61:44: 'component' is not defined no-undef
```